# Python if statements giving error when using negative floats

Tags: python, syntax-error

Here is my code which returns the timezone a set of coordinates are in. The IDE is telling me that a colon is expected somewhere in the nested if statement. The first if statement seems to be fine. and when I take out the negative signs in the other if statements they work fine. Thanks for any help!

```
def findTimeZone(coordinatesString):
    coordinates = coordinatesString.split(",")
    if 24.660845 <= float(coordinates[0]) <= 49.189787:
        if ‐87.518395 <= float(coordinates[1])  < ‐67.44457:
            return "eastern"
        elif ‐87.518395 <= float(coordinates[1]) < ‐101.998892:
            return "central"
        elif ‐101.998892 <= float(coordinates[1]) < ‐115.236428:
            return "mountain"
        elif ‐115.236428 <= float(coordinates[1]) <= ‐125.242264:
            return "pacific"
```

I could just assign each float to a variable but I would like to know why this is causing an error, Thanks.

Comment: Can you paste the exact error you are seeing.

Comment: I think this is an issue with encoding. Try writing the `-` manually in python IDLE.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you copy pasting the code from some document. In your code I could see the "-" negative symbol was some other special character

Try writing the "-" using your keyboard. This happens usualy due to unicode conversion issues because "-" symbol may look the same but act different

Answer (score 1):

Those aren't `-`'s like you think. Replace whatever it is you are using for the negative sign with an actual `-`.

Answer (score 0):

As an aside, and in addition to what both the other answers have said, your logic is wrong:

Use this instead:

```
def findTimeZone(coordinatesString):
    coordinates = coordinatesString.split(",")
    if 24.660845 <= float(coordinates[0]) <= 49.189787:
        if -87.518395 <= float(coordinates[1])  < -67.44457:
            return "eastern"
        elif -87.518395 > float(coordinates[1]) >= -101.998892:
            return "central"
        elif -101.998892 > float(coordinates[1]) >= -115.236428:
            return "mountain"
        elif -115.236428 > float(coordinates[1]) >= -125.242264:
            return "pacific"
```

Answer (score 0):

Let me try to help. I think you are getting error ***invalid character in identifier***

Identifiers or “names” can have only the following characters in python

**->** a to z (alphabets lowercase)

**->** A to Z (alphabets uppercase)

**->** 0 to 9 (digits)

**->** _ (underscore)